# Compile ffmpeg with mmal

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg with omx and mmal support for the raspberry pi zero on Debian Jessie. Omx seems fine and I got the headers from `libomxil-bellagio-dev` as per this stack overflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175644/ffmpeg-hardware-acceleration-on-raspberry-pi?rq=1

But I can't get it to recognise mmal - I get an error: `mmal not found`.

I've tried cloning userland `https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland.git` and copying the mmal folder to `/usr/include` but I still get the `mmal not found` error when running `./configure --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-mmal --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi`
`

Comment: Can you do `sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg`?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: What does `ffbuild/config.log` say towards the end?

Comment: Using debian: jessie